# Subversion Error: "Working copy [directory] not locked"

Tags: svn

I am trying to merge a directory in subversion, but I get the following error when I do so:

```
svn: Working copy '[directory name]' not locked'
```

I tried deleting the working directory and doing a fresh update, but that did not solve the issue. I also did a cleanup on the directory.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

In this instance, the parent directory has the same name as the sub directory. I don't know if this has anything to do with the error though.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this blog posting ([Obscure "svn mv" problem solved](http://news.e-scribe.com/145))...  I typically just remove the directory and grab fresh sources.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error using IDEA. I got around this by doing a tortoise svn cleanup in windows explorer, the equivalent cleanup in IDEA did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance using TortoiseSVN and some other client (Such as subversive or the commandline client?).  Sometimes Tortoise can unintentionally gum up other clients.  I don't remember what exactly causes this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your exact directory setup it's hard to say what is happening. One reason for this error message could be that one part of your merge command does refer to a directory that is not under version control.

Can you post the exact merge command that triggers the error?

Answer (score -1):

Try doing a clean-up and then an update. If that not work, please explain better your issue.